# UICollectionView cellForIndexPath returning wrong value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, row, nsindexpath

I am using a `UIButton` in `UICollectionVIew` and on the tap of that button i want to know the index of that `cell`, so for that i am using following code

```
  setFrpPriceButton.tag = indexPath.item;
```

but the value which i am getting is incorrect.
Following code i have written for my `UICollectionView`

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return frpTitleArray.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

    setFrpPriceButton = [UIButton new];
    setFrpPriceButton.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x2196f3);
    [setFrpPriceButton setTitle:@"SET PRICE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [setFrpPriceButton addTarget:self action:@selector(setFrpPriceClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    setFrpPriceButton.tag = selectedCellIndex;

    [frpCollectionViewCell addSubview:setFrpPriceButton];
//    [frpButtonLabel bringSubviewToFront:setFrpPriceButton];
    setFrpPriceButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];
    setFrpPriceButton.clipsToBounds = YES;

    [setFrpPriceButton mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make)
     {
         make.top.equalTo(frpButtonLabel);
         make.width.equalTo(frpCollectionViewCell).dividedBy(3);
         make.right.equalTo(frpCollectionViewCell);
         make.height.equalTo(frpTitleLabel);
     }];

    return frpCollectionViewCell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)displaySpecialityCollectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)displaySpecialityCollectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
}

-(UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)displaySpecialityCollectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)displaySpecialityCollectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}
```

Comment: - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;  there is no allocation for the cell. where you allocate "frpCollectionViewCell" ?

Comment: @ArunKumarP is right. What's `frpCollectionViewCell`? And don't add subviews, cells are reused.

Comment: why you did not create cell in XIB? ok use `setFrpPriceButton.tag = indexPath.row` its working for me

Comment: YourTableViewCell * frpCollectionViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ReuseCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath]; add this line in your cellForItemAtIndexPath. And make sure you have register your cell if there is no storyboard. [YourTable registerClass:[YourTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ReuseCellIdentifier" ];

Comment: I have initialised button, cell and Collection view.

Comment: frpCollectionVIewCell is the name of my collectionview cell

Comment: i tried using indexPath.row but i am not getting correct values

Comment: @Coder intilize cell in the "cellForItemAtIndexPath" function. it is not a sigle property in viewcontroller

Comment: I have already writtern this line of code also but forgot to paste that line here

frpCollectionViewCell = [frpCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: @Coder  addd this in cellForItemAtIndexPath   ----> YourTableViewCell * frpCollectionViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ReuseCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: what is your cell class name ?

Comment: @ArunKumarP i have this line in my code.

Comment: [frpCollectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

Comment: Now what error is showing ?

Comment: give me your updated code

Comment: I am clicking on second cell still indexPath value is coming as 0 instead of 1

Comment: @ArunKumarP i have already pasted the code

Comment: setFrpPriceButton.tag = indexPath.row;

Comment: I tried that also, but still i am getting incorrect value.

Comment: you should customize your cell and the button create in that custom class

Comment: @ArunKumarP How to do that and will this affect on indexPath.row value?

Answer (score -1):

You should write custom cell. and The button should be in the custom cell. And add set the tag for the button from `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

Now the issue is repeatedly add button in reused cell, so you will not get the correct tag.

For creating custom cell.
http://zeroheroblog.com/ios/how-to-create-simple-tableview-with-custom-cells